# Scanner isn't scanning my input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

i'm trying to read a line and then go into a if-statement. But after it have red the first input it just terminates. 
I have no idea what's wrong, and I can't figure it out

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Formler form = new Formler();
        Scanner Sscan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner Dscan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        System.out.println("Formler: Molmassa");
        input = Sscan.nextLine();

        if(input == "molmassa" || input == "Molmassa"){
            double m;
            double M;
            System.out.println("Massa: "); m = Dscan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Molmassa: "); M = Dscan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(form.getMolmassa(m, M));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your string comparisons are wrong. Use `input.equals("molmassa")` instead.

Answer (score 9):

Change your `if` statement to:

```
if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("molmassa") ) {  }
```

Then it should work as you expect. Remember always compare strings using `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` method. `==` compares object references not the actual values.

Answer (score 4):

You need to replace the equals checks:

```
 if(input == "molmassa" || input == "Molmassa"){
```

with the following;

```
 if(input.equals("molmassa") || input.equals("Molmassa")){
```

The first checks if the `String`s are the same object, whereas the second checks that they're the same value, which is what you need here.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in you `if` condition change it to

```
if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("molmassa) )
```

and every thing should work fine.

One more thing you don't need to have separate `Scanner` to take `String` and `double` input you can use one `Scanner` object for both the inputs.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(input == "molmassa" || input == "Molmassa"){}
```

You should equal `String` object with `equals` method or `equalsIgnoreCase` method.

```
if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Molmassa")){}
```

`==` is used for primitive equaling check.